# javascript - object referencing does not reference as expected

Tags: javascript

So I have the following code:

```js
async function runQuery(input)
{
  return input
}

async function createAccounts()
{
  return [1, 2]
}



(async function ()
{
  var
    creator1_ids =
        {},
    creator2_ids =
        {}

  let all_accounts =
    await createAccounts(2)

  const tables =
    [
      "list",
      "display_list",
      "map"
    ]

  for (let index in all_accounts)
  {
    let req =
      {
        session:
        {
          account:
            null
        }
      }
    req.session.account =
      all_accounts[index]
    let the_ids =
        index === 0
            ? creator1_ids
            : creator2_ids

    // Create item
    let result =
      await runQuery()

    the_ids.item = 
      1

    for (let table of tables)
    {
      result =
          await runQuery(table)
      the_ids[table] = 
          result
    }
  }
  
  console.log(creator1_ids)
  console.log(creator2_ids)  
})()
```

Now javascript uses objects as references (so if you assign another variable to an object, changing either variables would change the overall object), however this doesn't seem to be the case here.

`creator1_ids` remains empty, while only `creator2_ids` is filled. I'm expecting `creator1_ids` to be filled similarly.

But this works.

```js
async function runQuery(input)
{
  return input
}

async function createAccounts()
{
  return [1, 2]
}



(async function ()
{

    var
      creator1_ids =
          {},
      creator2_ids =
          {}
    let all_accounts =
        await createAccounts(2)

    const tables =
        [
            "list",
            "display_list",
            "map"
        ]

    async function generate(the_ids, account)
    {
       let req =
        {
          session:
          {
            account:
              null
          }
        }

      // Create item
      let result =
        await runQuery()

      the_ids.item = 
        1

      for (let table of tables)
      {
        result =
            await runQuery(table)
        the_ids[table] = 
            result + account
      }
    }

    await generate(creator1_ids, all_accounts[0])
    await generate(creator2_ids, all_accounts[1])

    console.log(creator1_ids)
    console.log(creator2_ids)
})()
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate why would I use `creator2_ids = creator1_ids`? I have a line using `the_ids` which should be holding the respective objects.

Comment: @Carcigenicate in the initialisation stage of `the_ids` I use a ternary: `let the_ids = index === 0 ? creator1_ids : creator2_ids`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion is invalid because the debugging is flawed.  Look more closely in your debugger, specifically on this line:

```
let the_ids =
  index === 0 ?
  creator1_ids :
  creator2_ids
```

`index` *never* equals `0`.  It *does* equal `'0'`.  So the `===` will never be `true`.

Change the comparison and you'll get the result you are expecting:

```
let the_ids =
  index == 0 ? // compare values regardless of type
  creator1_ids :
  creator2_ids
```

Then your loop will first modify `creator1_ids`, then `creator2_ids`.  Demo:

```js
async function runQuery(input) {
  return input
}

async function createAccounts() {
  return [1, 2]
}



(async function() {
  var creator1_ids = {},
    creator2_ids = {}

  let all_accounts = await createAccounts(2)

  const tables = [
    "list",
    "display_list",
    "map"
  ]

  for (let index in all_accounts) {
    let req = {
      session: {
        account: null
      }
    }
    req.session.account = all_accounts[index]
    let the_ids =
      index == 0 ?
      creator1_ids :
      creator2_ids

    // Create item
    let result = await runQuery()

    the_ids.item = 1

    for (let table of tables) {
      result = await runQuery(table)
      the_ids[table] = result
    }
  }

  console.log(creator1_ids)
  console.log(creator2_ids)
})()
```

Comment: blah, string, int equality!

Answer (score 2):

**Index**  is **string** so use quote. see below

```
let the_ids = index === '0'? creator1_ids : creator2_ids
```

instead of

```
let the_ids = index === 0  ? creator1_ids: creator2_ids
```